# MS Word footnotes in one and two columns in the same document

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

I'd like to have a short section of a Word 2016 document using footnotes in two column format.  Elsewhere, I'd like the footnotes to be a single column.

I'm able to make the two column footnotes work, but it's being applied to the whole document, and I've been unsuccessful using section breaks.  Is there a method to change the footnote formatting in different sections of the document?